# How to differentiate two routes in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I have two different routes

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
```

and

```
@GetMapping("/{username}")
```

But whenever I am unable to access the second route. Whenever I try to hit the second route only the first one is getting triggered. How can I create a distinguish between them. I am using springboot.

I am expecting any solution that would work

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, how should the framework know if the path segment is an id or username.

The easiest way is to use different paths, like `/user/{username}`.

Another option that could work (depending on your ids and usernames) is to specify a pattern for the different parameters. This could be like `@GetMapping("/{id:\\d*}")` using regular expressions.